# asynchronous socket: several requests but the server only gets the first one

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing through a socket from a FF add-on to a java server. I write several requests but the server only gets the first one. I don't have a clue of what is happening.

Here is my code:

```
const {Cc,Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");

var toSend = ["hi1\n", "hi2\n"];

var {NetUtil} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

function sendNextString(outstream) {
  if (!toSend.length)
    return;  // Nothing left to send

  var outputData = toSend.shift();
  console.log(outputData);

  var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
        .createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);

  instream.setData(outputData, outputData.length);

  NetUtil.asyncCopy(instream, outstream, function(aResult) {  
    if (!Components.isSuccessCode(aResult))
        console.log("ERROR: writing to socket")
    });
}


exports.main = function() {
    try  {
        // At first, we need a nsISocketTransportService
        var transportService =  
            Cc["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsISocketTransportService);  

        // Try to connect to localhost:2222
        var transport = transportService.createTransport(null, 0, "localhost", 6666, null);  

        var stream = transport.openInputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED,null,null); 
        var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
            .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream); 

        // Initialize
        instream.init(stream);
        var outstream = transport.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);

        var dataListener = { 
            onStartRequest: function(request, context){},

            onStopRequest: function(request, context, status){
                instream.close();
                outstream.close();
            }, 

            onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) { 
                var data = instream.read(count); 
                console.log(data);

                // Write data
                sendNextString(outstream);        
            }, 
        };

        var pump = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIInputStreamPump); 
        pump.init(stream, -1, -1, 0, 0, false); 
        pump.asyncRead(dataListener, null); 

        // Write data
        sendNextString(outstream);

    } catch (e){ 
        console.log("Error" + e.result + ": " + e.message); 
        return e; 
    } return null;
};
```

So, when I run it, I get:

```
Client > hi1
Server > bye1
Client > hi2
```

And it should be:

```
Client > hi1
Server > bye1
Client > hi2
Server > bye2
```

**Edit:** Added a callback into the asyncCopy call to check for errors, but it works correctly.

**Edit2:** Debugged the loop in the server for reading the add-on requests gets bloqued at reading from the *in* stream the second time.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  if (inputLine.equals("-1")) break;
  System.out.println("Client < " + inputLine);
  outputLine = process(inputLine);
  out.println(outputLine);
  System.out.println("Server > " + outputLine);
}
```